# Kendo UI: Unable to bind data to list view using MVVM

Tags: javascript, mvvm, kendo-ui

I am new to kendo ui mvvm and am facing the follow issue:

**Scenario**
I need to populate few fields in a div whose role is a listview, using the MVVM format.

The data comes from the dataSource and I am getting an unusual error. I am unable to bind the fields from the data source to the div.

Follow is my JSBin Sample: http://jsbin.com/ajoyug/6/edit

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2013.1.319/styles/kendo.common.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2013.1.319/styles/kendo.rtl.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2013.1.319/styles/kendo.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2013.1.319/styles/kendo.dataviz.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2013.1.319/styles/kendo.dataviz.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2013.1.319/styles/kendo.mobile.all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2013.1.319/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="myListView" data-role="listView" data-bind="source:dataSource">
    <span data-bind="text:prodName"></span>
    <span data-bind="text:qty"></span>
    <span data-bind="text:total"></span>
    <span data-bind="text:price"></span>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var data = [
    {
    "Id":1,
    "img":"../public/images/product/shoes.png",
    "code":"00021543",
    "fullProdName":"Jimmy Choo - Simone Pump Shoes",
    "prodName":"Simone Pump Shoes",
    "description":"A perfect Red carpet companion. Jimmy Choo shoes spells success and glamour. Be the talk of the town...",
    "price":"1500.0",
    "total":"1500.0",
    "qty":"1",
    "discount":"0.00",
    "brand":"Jimmy Choo",
    "category":"Shoes",
    "points":"100",
    "tax":"0.00" }
];

  var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    data: data, 
    pagesize: 10,
    schema: {
      model: {
        id: "Id",
        fields: {
          prodName: { editable: false},
          qty: { editable: true},
          price: { editable: false},
          total : {editable :false}
        }
      }
    }
  });

dataSource.read();

  var listViewModel = kendo.observable({
    dataSource:dataSource
  });
  kendo.bind($("#myListView"), listViewModel);
});
```

Kindly help me out. I saw many samples available online, but they used templates to bind multiple values or they were'nt suiting my requirement..Hence I thought of creating my own JSBin Sample and ask where am I getting stuck...

**Questions**
How shall I bind the fields from a dataSource?

My end motive is to bind the div with the values in the dataSource..Is there any other method to do that if not setting it as a listview?

Thanks!!

Hardik

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your JavaScript looked good.  You had some problems with your HTML though.  The `data-role` attribute needs to be `"listview"`.  Rather than putting 4 spans inside your listview `div`, you should really use a template, and reference it by ID.

It's also important to note that your template must have a root element, because kendo only performs binding on the first element in the template.

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2013.1.319/styles/kendo.common.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2013.1.319/styles/kendo.rtl.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2013.1.319/styles/kendo.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2013.1.319/styles/kendo.dataviz.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2013.1.319/styles/kendo.dataviz.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2013.1.319/styles/kendo.mobile.all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2013.1.319/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
<script id="tmp" type="text/x-kendo-template">
  <div>
    <span data-bind="text:prodName"></span><br/>
    <span data-bind="text:qty"></span><br/>
    <span data-bind="text:total"></span><br/>
    <span data-bind="text:price"></span>
  </div>
</script>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div
    id="myListView"
    data-role="listview"
    data-bind="source: dataSource"
    data-template="tmp">
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var data = [
    {
    "Id":1,
    "img":"../public/images/product/shoes.png",
    "code":"00021543",
    "fullProdName":"Jimmy Choo - Simone Pump Shoes",
    "prodName":"Simone Pump Shoes",
    "description":"A perfect Red carpet companion. Jimmy Choo shoes spells success and glamour. Be the talk of the town...",
    "price":"1500.0",
    "total":"1500.0",
    "qty":"1",
    "discount":"0.00",
    "brand":"Jimmy Choo",
    "category":"Shoes",
    "points":"100",
    "tax":"0.00" }
];

  var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    data: data, 
    pagesize: 10,
    schema: {
      model: {
        id: "Id",
        fields: {
          prodName: { editable: false},
          qty: { editable: true},
          price: { editable: false},
          total : {editable :false}
        }
      }
    }
  });

  var listViewModel = kendo.observable({
    dataSource:dataSource
  });
  kendo.bind($("#myListView"), listViewModel);
});
```

Comment: Hi Dan!! Thank you so much for the reply!! That worked.. :) Just want your advice.. I am currently new to Kendo UI MVVM and I face many small small issues for which I keep googling most of the day.. Could you suggest me links which I should study? or any blogs? I can sometime find a Non-MVVM solution but cant actually implement the MVVM way... Thanks again for the feedback!!

Comment: I have just familiarized myself with their documentation site.  There's a lot of data there even you have to search different places for it.  Between the docs and the demos it's mostly all there.